# How to show custom time In dom using new Date() object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, date, object, dom

I am a beginner in javascript, what I am trying to do is using `new Date()` object and show a custom hour, minutes and seconds but in `countDown()` function I have to pass full date and it starts counting from that date.

My goal is for example I give number 1 as (hour) and then it should start counting down.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(holder) {

    var controller = {
      holder: holder,
      end: null,
      intervalID: 0,
      display: function () {
        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;

        var msg = "";

        var now = new Date();

        var distance = controller.end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

          clearInterval(controller.intervalID);
          controller.holder.innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

          return;
        }

        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
        controller.holder.innerHTML = hours + ' Hours | ' + minutes + ' Minutes | ' + seconds + ' Seconds ';

      }
    };

    this.countDown = function (end) {
      controller.end = end;
      controller.intervalID = setInterval(controller.display, 1000);
    };
  }
}

var timers = {};

timers.one = new Timer(document.getElementById("one"));
timers.two = new Timer(document.getElementById("two"));
timers.three = new Timer(document.getElementById("three"));


//Hier I should be able to give a number
timers.one.countDown(new Date("Feb 30, 2022 15:37:25"));
timers.two.countDown(new Date(2022, 10, 29, 12, 40, 40));
timers.three.countDown(new Date(2022, 11, 9, 13, 45, 30));
```

```html
 <div id="one"></div>
 <div id="two"></div>
 <div id="three"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I could manage and find an answer to this question, here we need to convert the time to second and use the `getTime()` method, for this reason we need to write to function to do this job. In the following you can see the code.

```js
function CreateEndTime(hours, minutes, seconds)
 {
   const result = new Date(new Date().getTime() + ConvertInMilliSeconds(hours, minutes, seconds));
   return result;
 }
 
 function ConvertInMilliSeconds(hours, minutes, seconds)
 {
   const result = (((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60) + seconds;
   return 1000 * result;
 }
```